# Can I execute update queries dealing with BLOB using Ant's SQL task?

Tags: sql, ant, blob

Is it possible to deal with BLOB datatypes when my update query is run from within an Ant script's `<sql>` task? The data that I'd like to update is located in an external file. The solution should be compatible with Oracle and MSSQL, however separate ant targets for the two db platforms are acceptable. I also thought of using a Groovy task for this task, however I'm not sure how to do it in Groovy either.

Comment: Your would require a custom task. The tutorial covers a bit  http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html

Comment: I think you could write this as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant is build tool. SQL task was introduced to help in build related step which we would expect  to be some what simple like deleting records from table, quick query etc.

For any advanced database operations such as this, you are better off [with custom task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html). It is straightforward to write custom task. Other option is write java code, and call it via [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task.